Implementing Server-Side Operations in Next.js with Prisma for a Large Dataset
I'm transitioning an application from React to Next.js and replacing a Node.js + Express + MariaDB backend with Prisma. In the old setup, I managed a large dataset through an API route that allowed filtering and sorting operations, using query parameters to store these settings client-side. However, I'm unsure how to replicate this functionality in Next.js while maintaining server-side operations.
Is it possible to maintain server-side data operations such as sorting and filtering in Next.js, similar to my previous setup? How can I adapt the current method to handle dynamic queries based on user input? Additionally, any recommendations for tools or libraries that might simplify this process would be greatly appreciated.
Currently, I have a basic setup in Next.js using Prisma, where I fetch the first 500 records sorted by the updated_at date, as shown below:
"use server";

import db from "@/db/db";

export async function getEntries() {
  let entries = await db.ekw_entries.findMany({
    take: 500,
    orderBy: {
      updated_at: "desc",
    },
    include: {
      ekw_cities: true,
    },
  });

  const count = await db.ekw_entries.count();

  return { data: entries , meta: { total: count } };
}

I pass this data to a data table component from shadcn/ui, which only allows sorting and filtering on the loaded 500 records. I need to enable refetching the data with new filters and sorting parameters applied.
import { columns } from "@/components/site/entries/EntriesColumns";
import { EntriesDataTable } from "@/components/site/entries/EntriesDataTable";
import { getEntries } from "@/lib/actions/entriesActions";

export default async function Test() {
  const entries = await getEntries();
  return <EntriesDataTable columns={columns} data={entries.data} />;
}

